# ¿Cómo se hace un botón "Ver Más" correctamente con una imágen con Html y Css?

Tags: html, css

Resulta que tengo una tabla en donde en la última celda estoy mostrando 4 imágenes, el tema es que cada fila puede llegar a tener más de esas 4 y para mostrar las otras quiero redireccionar a otra página.

Ya tengo en la imágen el Hover que muestre el "Ver Más", pero no son del mismo tamaño y si uso la etiqueta `<a></a>`, aunque lo redirecciona, se sigue viendo mal y para nada agradable a la vista.

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid; 
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft {
    transition: all .5s ease;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.imagenPruebaTopRight {
    object-position: right top;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomLeft {
    object-position: left bottom;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.imagenPruebaBottomRight {
    object-position: left bottom;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.imagenPruebaTopLeft:hover, .imagenPruebaBottomRight:hover, .imagenPruebaTopRight:hover, .imagenPruebaBottomLeft:hover{
        transform: scale(1.2);
}

.tdImagenes{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.columna {
    flex: 20%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0 4px;
    width: 100px;

}

.columna img{
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.texto {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.verMas{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
}

.columna figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.columna figure:hover > .texto{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.columna figure:hover > .texto .verMas{
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>CUIT / DNI</th>
                    <th>Número de pedido</th>
                    <th>Pedido Sap</th>
                    <th>Imágenes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                    <td>1111</td>
                    <td>2222</td>
                    <td>2222</td>
                    <td class="tdImagenes">
                            <div class="columna">
                                <img class="imagenPruebaTopLeft" src="~/imgAndroid/Celular.jpg" data-img-mostrar="0"/>
                                <img class="imagenPruebaBottomLeft" src="~/imgAndroid/Horno.jpg" data-img-mostrar="1"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columna">
                                <img class="imagenPruebaTopRight" src="~/imgAndroid/Monitor.jpg" data-img-mostrar="2"/>  
                                <figure>
                                    <img class="imagenPruebaBottomRight" src="~/imgAndroid/Taza.jpg" data-img-mostrar="3"/>
                                    <div class="texto"><p class="verMas">Ver Más</p></div>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Por alguna razón que desconozco, en el snippet se ve mal, pero adjunto imágen como se me ve a mí. Me gustaría saber si me podrían decir en dónde estoy mal o si me pueden brindar un ejemplo.

Muchas gracias!.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Al final era un tema de la imagen en sí (ya que no me era posible cambiarles las propiedades de `width` y `height`, y también del css

el css le cambié esta propiedad:

```
.columna figure:hover .texto {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Por

```
.columna figure:hover > a > .texto {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

y el html me quedó asi:

```
<figure>                             
     <img class="imagenPruebaBottomRight" src="~/imgAndroid/PanelSolar.jpg" data-img-mostrar="3"/>
      <a href="~/Home/Pedido">
         <div class="texto"><p class="verMas">Ver Más</p></div>
      </a>
</figure>
```

Era una tontería.